# how to iterate over a queryset in django as i get 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, drf-queryset

I want to get the object from a queryset

```
 accounts = group.get_external_accounts(include_sub_groups=True)

    try:
        account: StripeExternalAccount = accounts.get(account_id)
    except StripeExternalAccount.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have tried this. it works fine but i want to do it through try except

```
   account: StripeExternalAccount = None
        for acc in accounts:
             if acc.id == int(account_id):
                account = acc
                break
        if not account:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: What is `get_external_accounts ` and `get` ? Kindly provide relevant piece of code.

Comment: get_external_accounts is model method to get the queryset 
and i get <QuerySet [(50,), (77,), (78,), (99,), (119,), (123,), (125,)]>

Comment: @UmairMohammad  i want to now get 99 from the above queryset

Comment: Hard to devise solution without context, anyways try `accounts = group.get_external_accounts(include_sub_groups=True).values_list('id', flat=True)[3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its name implies, `.values_list()` returns a `list` of values and a `list` object doesn't have a `.get()` method. If `get_external_accounts` returns a queryset, you can simply use the `.get()` on the queryset:

```
accounts = group.get_external_accounts(include_sub_groups=True)

try:
    account: StripeExternalAccount = accounts.get(id=account_id)
except StripeExternalAccount.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

If you need the list of account IDs later in your code, you could add:

```
account_ids = accounts.values_list('id')
```

It might be worth pointing out that getting a single item with `accounts.get()` *and* getting the list of all IDs with `accounts.values_list('id')` will perform two queries to your database.

If you have multiple accounts with the same id and want to get the first one, use

```
account: StripeExternalAccount = accounts.filter(id=account_id).first()
```

Comment: Did you use `accounts.get()` or `accounts.get(id=account_id)`?

Comment: i used accounts.get(id=account_id)

Comment: and when i use
 account: StripeExternalAccount = accounts.get(account_id)
it gives 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: I updated my answer. If this does not solve your problem. Please edit your question and add the code you now have

Comment: it worked but i dont have multiple accounts with same id

Comment: <QuerySet [(36,), (37,), (38,), (83,)]>  this was the queryset for accounts.values_list('id')

Comment: and my account_id was 36

Comment: then `accounts.get(id=account_id)` should not raise `MultipleObjectsReturned`

Comment: but i have checked the database id is the pk and it is different for all

Comment: when we use accounts.filter(id=account_id) it gives 
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
@daniel